# Azure B2C MFA phone factor verification retry handling in custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When using the phone factor technical profile for MFA, the default behavior after 3 incorrect code entries is to redirect the user back to the specified URI with an error saying *maximum retries for MFA exceeded*. However, the default behavior for email MFA is to simply show an error message and give the user an option to send a new code or cancel.

Is there a way to specify the allowed number of retries for phone MFA or to specify that the phone MFA should display an error in the template without redirecting with an error code?

My phonefactor technical profile:

```xml
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify">
          <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.PhoneFactorProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.phonefactor</Item>
            <Item Key="ManualPhoneNumberEntryAllowed">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserIdForMFA" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdForMFA" PartnerClaimType="UserId" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="Verified.OfficePhone" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPhoneNumberEntered" PartnerClaimType="newPhoneNumberEntered" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-MFA" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Example error from phone MFA: https://jwt.ms/#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C90151%3a+User+has+exceeded+the+maximum+number+for+retries+for+multi-factor+authentication.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+0815e707-54b1-4a67-913e-7682742d1c65%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2019-11-13+14%3a13%3a39Z%0d%0a

Comment: Just ran into this today and facing the same issue, I want to change the behavior post 3 sms verification fails, did you find a way?

Comment: No, but I haven't check again since posting this questions, so there might have been some updates in the past year. I know b2c is frequently updated

Comment: Thanks. We think that the PhoneFactorProtocolProvider is not a complete feature and is not a complete solution to the above and other things we are facing, so we switched the TechnicalProfile for the phone verification to the older SelfAssertedAttributeProvider